# How to get Multicast working in VirtualBox Guest OS on OSX

Tags: c#, udp, virtualbox, multicast

Im tearing my hair out trying to get Multicast to work under virtual box with an OSX host and Win7 guests. My multicast code in general works fine on a real network of Windows7 machines but I need to be able to develop away from it.

I read that it was possible that VB was creating additional interfaces and one of them was getting my multicast packets that couldnt repeat it, so I wrote the below code to try to deal with that but it still fails in VB under InternalNetwork or HostOnly.

Do I need to by physically wired to a network (not wifi) for it to work? Or am I still doing something else wrong?

edit: Simplified my code somewhat, still doesn't work.

```
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

// Get netowrk info
int defaultPort = 5050;
string localName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry hostEntry = new IPHostEntry();
hostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(localName);
IPAddress localAddress = hostEntry.AddressList[0];

// create a socket pair for every interafce
for(int i=0;i<nics.Length;i++)
{
    #region Make Outgoing Socket on Interface

    if (!nics[i].SupportsMulticast)
    {
        continue; // skip this one
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Adding socket to nic: " + nics[i].Name);
    // output interface
    Socket mcastSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    // Bind the socket to default IP address and port.
    mcastSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localAddress,4568+i));

    // Select Adapter for outgoing Multicast packets );
    int optionValue = (int)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(i);

    // Multicast Address - To add membership : ");
    IPAddress mcastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("224.5.6.7");

    // Port number - Where Multicast members are listening : ");
    int mcastPort = 4567;
    MulticastOption mcastOpt = new MulticastOption(mcastAddress,localAddress);

    // Add membership to the group.
    mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, mcastOpt);

    // Set the required interface for outgoing multicast packets.
    mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastInterface, optionValue);

    mcastSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(mcastAddress,4567));

    // add to transmission list
    transmissionList.Add(mcastSocket);

    #endregion
}

#region Make Incoming Socket on Interface

// make socket to read for incoming multicast
Socket inSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
inSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 4567));
inSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,                SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(multicastIpAddr));
receptionList.Add(inSocket);
```

Comment: I solved it.  There were a number of issues.  They are all laid out in this blog: http://unseenu.quora.com/Making-Multicast-Work-on-VirtualBox-in-C

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer here. Put the link to the answer in the blog post and outline your answer in one or two short sentences. Then mark this question as answered. That helps others looking for the same problem - and helps those looking for unanswered questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

excerpt from the blog mentioned above

There may be other ways, and not all of these steps may really be necessary , but this is what worked for me:

1. Download and install the latest VirtualBox from Oracle VM VirtualBox also download and install the Oracle VirtualBox Extension Pack (might not be necessary, but I did.)
2. Install a copy of Win7 into a VirtualBox VM.
3. Clone the VM to create a second machine.
   Critically Important:  A clone starts with the same MAC address as its parent. This messed me up for a long time. Go into Network Settings->Advanced  for the clone and request that it assign you a new MAC by pressing the circular arrows next to the MAC.  (This only works when the virtual machine is powered down.)
4. Set the network type setting for both machines to "Internal Network".  (Note that this will isolate them from your host and the internet.)
5. On the command line of your host, enable dhcp  (this also may not be absolutely necessary but it is what I did.  As an alternative you could also manually config your IP for both machines).  Assuming you used the default internal network name of "intnet", you can do that like this (all on one line):
   dhcpserver add --netname intnet --ip 10.10.10.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --enable --lowerip 10.10.10.10 --upperip 10.10.10.128

**Critically Important:**  I
In the environment created by VirtualBox there are multiple NICs that claim to be multicast capable.  However, they are lying.  Furthermore, because of the way VirtualBox assigns metrics, your outgoing socket will get assigned to a liar who will happily gobble up your multicast messages and not send them on.
The solution is to open an outgoing socket specifically on every NIC that claims to be multicast capable and send your outgoing packets to all of them.  Below is my code that opens the sockets and makes a list.  Just foreach on the list when sending the packet.

```
NetworkInterface[] nics =   
                  NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
  // Get netowrk info
  int defaultPort = 5050;
  string localName = Dns.GetHostName();

  IPHostEntry hostEntry = new IPHostEntry();
  hostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(localName);
  IPAddress localAddress = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
   for(int i=0;i<nics.Length;i++){
            if (!nics[i].SupportsMulticast)
            {
                continue; // skip this one
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Adding socket to nic: " + nics[i].Name);
            // output interface
            Socket mcastSocket = new 
                Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                     SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

            // Bind the socket to default IP address and port.
            mcastSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localAddress,4568+i));

            //Select Adapter for outgoing Multicast packets );

            int optionValue = (int)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(i);

            //Multicast Address - To add membership : 
            IPAddress mcastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("224.5.6.7");

            // Port number - Where Multicast members are listening 
            int mcastPort = 4567;
            MulticastOption mcastOpt = new
                MulticastOption(mcastAddress,localAddress);

             // Add membership to the group.
            mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
                SocketOptionName.AddMembership, mcastOpt);

            // Set the required interface for outgoing multicast packets.
            mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
                SocketOptionName.MulticastInterface, optionValue);

            mcastSocket.Connect(new 
                IPEndPoint(mcastAddress,4567));

            // add to transmission list
            transmissionList.Add(mcastSocket);
        }
```